# cell needs to show always the last sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need some help with an issue. (THIS ISSUE IS SOLVED)

I'm making an workbook who contains years as names for the sheets.
I'm busy making an macro to copy everytime 4 years 3 normal years and one leap year.
But to complete what I'm making I need one of the two things:

1. one cell needs to always show the last sheet name, ore.
2. one cell needs to show the value of the next sheet of the selected cell.

I have found this VBA code here below for previous sheet but I don't know how to ajust it to show the next sheet.

```
Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range)
    Dim xIndex As Long
    Application.Volatile
    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index
    If xIndex > 1 Then _
        PrevSheet = Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address)
End Function
```

well i have managed to solve the issues I had, i found out how to change the code above, i have changed it like this for who will need it to.

```
Function nextSheet(RCell As Range)
    Dim xIndex As Long
    Application.Volatile
    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index
    If xIndex > 1 Then _
        nextSheet = Worksheets(xIndex + 1).Range(RCell.Address)
End Function
```

and to prevent an error on my sheets, i used the following code (=IFERROR(nextSheet(A1);E5)) so that on the last (newest) sheet I won't get an error. on E5 stands the same name (year) as the latest sheetname(year).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, samples of expected results help, but this might get you started without VBA.

On a new worksheet create a simple table (Two Columns)

Go to Formulas Tab and click on Define Name, create a new name SheetNames
and in refers to enter =REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")

[image]

The in cell B2 =IFERROR(INDEX(SheetNames,A2),""). Since it is a table it will automatically populate all the sheet names.

[image]

Take Care,
Brad

Comment: thank you Brad for your answer, well i'm using this code to automatically name an new sheet.           

Sub Copyrenameworksheet()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    If wh.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("A2").Value
    End If
    wh.Activate
End Sub

So i need that cell to name always the last sheet, so i can put an formula on that cell to do +1 so the next new created sheet names one number higher.

Comment: If there is information that would clarify your question, but that isn’t in your question, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1682917/edit) to put it there. Don’t hide vital information in comments.